# What is the simple way to hide series data in HighStocks Navigator

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Am working on Highstocks and want to hide series data that is displayed in Navigator. Tried few approaches and Googled enough but no luck.

Here is the sample [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/suman_jsfiddle/mc9mL17m/)

The simple approach i tried was :

```
series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur,
        showInNavigator: false
    }]
```

This `showInNavigator` configuration removes X-Axis co-ordinates also from navigator which i want to retain.

I did try the solution provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971263) but nothing worked.

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: These are config for navigator http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator. you are using `showInNavigator` ,what you want i am not getting.Add screen shot

Comment: @Deep If u look at JSFiddle link that I have given in question, Navigator (below scrollable section) has series drawn inside it. I want to get rid of that series inside Navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS to hide the scrollbar. `showInNavigator: false` will hide navigator.

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur,
        showInNavigator: false
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-scrollbar{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```

Another Update

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    navigator: {
        series: {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            lineWidth: 0
        }
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

```html
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/usdeur.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still confusion what you want. Still i added answer

Comment: Check the update answer. I think this is exactly what you want

Comment: glad it helped :)